# React: function in value, passed from context provider doesn't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, post, fetch-api, react-context

I'm trying to work with Django rest framework and now i want to send a `POST` message to log users in.
im using context to have the login function in the whole app

```js
// index.js
...
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <AuthProvider>
        <App />
      </AuthProvider>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>
)
```

`AuthProvider` is the component which context is created

```
// AuthContext.jsx

export const AuthContext = createContext(null)

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {

    const loginUser = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        const response = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/token/', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ 
                'phone_number': e.target.phoneNumber.value,          // this is line 18
                'password': e.target.password.value,
            })
        })
        
        const data = await response.json()
        // console.log('data: ', data)
    }

    const contextData = {
        loginUser: loginUser,
    }

    return(
        <AuthContext.Provider value={contextData}>
            {children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

and when im using the `loginUser` function in a form it throws an error

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')
> [image]

this is the component which uses the `loginUser` function:

```
// LoginForm.jsx
export const LoginPage = () => {
  let {loginUser} = useContext(AuthContext)
  return (
    <>
      ...
      <form onSubmit={loginUser}>
        <input name="phoneNumber" />
        <input name="password" />
      </form>
      ...
    </>
  )
}
```

i dont understand why this happens because when i `console.log` the `loginUser` in `LoginForm` prints the function correctly

BTW, i created a simple function(log sth in console) and passed it with `loginUser` in `contextData`. that function worked fine.

all imports are done. there is no problem with importing

ANY kinda help is appreciated. thank you

Comment: try `e.currentTarget.elements.phoneNumber.value`

Comment: I have created a sandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-dust-6rdzoz?file=/src/App.js. It seems all good, catch error only in fetch (expected).  Try to log e parameter  or e.target inside loginUser()

Comment: i kinda found the problem. the issue comes from text inputs not the context or anything else. i created a simple login form (bare minimum). and it worked. there is no problem with context or function or anything else.